# How to organize hierarchical structure in custom post type with taxonomy (like with categories)

Tags: wordpress, hierarchy, custom-post-type, taxonomy, permalinks

can anyone help me with  custom post type arhive? I want there organise taxonomy term structure like with categories.

Full image url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzl4y.png

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your functions.php file

```
function create_post_types() {
    register_post_type('myPostType',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'My post types' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'My post type' )
            ),

            'taxonomies' => array('category'), //this is the 'magic' one

            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' )
            )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_types' );
```

**Edit**

If you want to only show the custom post type categories in the editor consider using custom fields with ACF: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

or you add your own taxonomy type:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57493/custom-taxonomy-specific-to-a-custom-post-type

```
function themes_taxonomy() {  
    register_taxonomy(  
        'themes_categories',  //The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces). 
        'themes',        //post type name
        array(  
            'hierarchical' => true,  
            'label' => 'Themes store',  //Display name
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'themes', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
                'with_front' => false // Don't display the category base before 
            )
        )  
    );  
}  
add_action( 'init', 'themes_taxonomy');
```

haven't tried that one though

Comment: I understand that you using taxonomy 'category', but i dont want use them, because in post editor all categories will be shown from all post types.

Now main idea is to create specific taxonomy for specific custom post type.

Comment: Maybe You know how to show list of categories in post editor only from current custom post type?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do, is when registering the custom taxonomy, you specify which post type it belongs to. Like so:

```
add_action('init', 'product_tags', 0);
function product_tags() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Product Tags', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Product Tag', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Product Tags' )
        // etc...
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array(
            'slug'                  => 'product-tag',
            'with_front'            => true,
            'hierarchical'          => true
        ),
    );
    // 'products' is the name of the Custom Post Type, ensuring that it will not pop up under any other post types.
    register_taxonomy( 'product_tags', 'products', $args );
}
```